# I deployed my token on testnet on bsc chain and deployed success but total supply not showing on bscscan testnet and my cap value showing on remix?

Tags: erc-20, contract-deployment, etherscan, bscscan

hi i deployed my token on testnet on bsc chain and deployed success but total supply not showing on bscscan testnet and my cap value showing on remix after deployed contract by checking with interaction buttons on remix. this is my contract address 0xE90bb23b92d6507eAC2Aa62Ec83BaE6a6921DD2a.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "./ERC20.sol";
import "./ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "./MinterRole.sol";

contract PlayCore is ERC20("PlayCore Token", "PCT"), ERC20Burnable, MinterRole {
    address public owner;
    uint256 private _totalMinted;
    uint256 private _cap;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _setupDecimals(8);
        _cap = 9000000000000000000000;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "caller not owner");
        _;
    }

    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal override {
        super._mint(account, amount);
        _totalMinted = _totalMinted.add(amount);
    }

    function cap() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _cap;
    }

    function totalMinted() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalMinted;
    }

    function mintBulk(address[] memory accounts, uint256[] memory amounts)
        public
        onlyMinter
        returns (bool)
    {
        require(accounts.length == amounts.length, "arrays must have same length");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            require(amounts[i] > 0, "amount must be greater than 0");
            _mint(accounts[i], amounts[i]);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

        if (from == address(0)) {
            // When minting tokens
            require(totalMinted().add(amount) <= cap(), "ERC20Capped: cap exceeded");
        }
    }

    function addMinter(address account) public override onlyOwner {
        _addMinter(account);
    }

    function removeMinter(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _removeMinter(account);
    }
}
```

[image: remix screen]
[image: bsctestnet]
[image: bsctestnet1]

Comment: Two observations: 1/ the contract isn't verified, 2/ no transfer operation was performed. Etherscan/Bscscan are closed source thirdy party block explorers if you have specific issues it is better to ask to their customer support.

Answer (score 0):

BscScan is using ERC20 standard's totalSupply function to read your token's totalSupply. Since you are not actually initializing the _totalSupply variable it is set to 0 by default.

Comment: Please can suggest the solution what to do @Kostiantyn Kurbatskyi

Comment: Initialize the _totalSupply variable in your constructor with the desired value. @Krishna

Comment: I'm new to coding so can you highlight in my code and attach here so I can understand well please @ PiNaKa30

Comment: ```constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _setupDecimals(8);
        _totalSupply = 9000000000000000000000;
    }```